# get next value of cursor if the column not found?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am looping through cursor using record, but when this loop is unable to find a value,
it stops executing the script. So is there anyway to let the loop continue if record is empty ?

```
declare 
cust_id info.CUSTOMER_ID%type; 
SPNum info.spnumber%type; 
EnterTicketDate EnteryDate%type;

cursor mycursor is 
select S_P_NUM ,_START_TIME
from info
where UPPER (STATUS)='YES';

begin 

for myRecord in mycursor
loop
dbms_output.put_line(SPNum);
select PID into cust_id from info where dn_num=SPNum;
dbms_output.put_line('ID is '|| cust_id);
end loop;
end;
```

I am thinking about avoiding this case by handing the data_not_found and move to the next value of the loop but how and is it possible ?

can I use the nextval keyword anyway?

```
declare 
cust_id info.CUSTOMER_ID%type; 
SPNum info.spnumber%type; 
EnterTicketDate EnteryDate%type;

cursor mycursor is 
select S_P_NUM ,_START_TIME
from info
where UPPER (STATUS)='YES';

begin 

for myRecord in mycursor
loop
dbms_output.put_line(SPNum);
select PID into cust_id from info where dn_num=SPNum;
dbms_output.put_line('ID is '|| cust_id);
exit when myRecord%notfound;
end loop;

exception 
when data_not_found
-- here is a recall for the next value of my record 
end;
```

Comment: Can you please show some code? It is harder to tell what the problem without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `CURSOR` returns `NO_DATA_FOUND` it means no more data to read from it.

```
for myRecord in mycursor
loop
-- exit when myRecord%notfound;
/* NOT NEEDED as FOR LOOP itself will terminate on NO DATA in mycursor */
dbms_output.put_line(SPNum);
select PID into cust_id from info where dn_num=SPNum;
dbms_output.put_line('ID is '|| cust_id);
end loop;
```

Hope you need this.

```
declare 
cust_id info.CUSTOMER_ID%type; 
SPNum info.spnumber%type; 
EnterTicketDate EnteryDate%type;

cursor mycursor is 
select S_P_NUM ,_START_TIME
from info
where UPPER (STATUS)='YES';

begin 
for myRecord in mycursor
loop
  IF(myRecord.S_P_NUM IS NOT NULL)
  THEN
     BEGIN
       dbms_output.put_line(myRecord.S_P_NUM);
       select PID into cust_id from info where dn_num=myRecord.S_P_NUM;
       dbms_output.put_line('ID is '|| cust_id);
     EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       dbms_output.put_line('NOT FOUND FOR SPNum '|| myRecord.S_P_NUM);
       CONTINUE; -- Process Next S_P_NUM from cursor
     END;
  END IF;
end loop;
END;
```

Comment: its not recocnized myRecord as implicit record

Comment: Sorry I don't get you, mean to say `myRecord` doesn't hold entire record of your `SELECT` ?

Comment: it said I have to declare myRecord

Comment: no you need not declare.. oracle do it implicitly for you!

Comment: yea i know but when I tried the way of ur coade I faced that error

Comment: I just edited the answer to add full PL/SQL Block.! It should compile well.! If you get an error, can you paste the error please?

Comment: cloud pls just tell me why u r using two begin ? 
why is not a syntax of the pl blocks ?

Comment: It is called _Nesting_ of PL/SQL Blocks.. Any `Exception` raised , the control flow would be thrown out of the Current `BEGIN-END` Block. SO, when we dont want that, wrap the code that throws _exception_ in another `BEGIN-END` and handle the exception aptly!.. It is very similar `try-catch` in `Java`